# Add @RenderSection to html helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I need to add the code to an html helper of mine to generate the equivalent of the following html:

```
<div id="buttonrow">@RenderSection("ButtonRow", false)</div>
```

Is this possible?

This doesn't work...

```
public static MvcHtmlString ButtonRow(this HtmlHelper helper)
{  
TagBuilder buttonRow = new TagBuilder("div");
buttonRow.GenerateId("buttonRow");
buttonRow.InnerHtml = "@RenderSection('ButtonRow', false)";

return MvcHtmlString.Create(buttonRow.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@RenderSection` is a server-generated fragment of code. That is, when the view is rendered by the Razor engine, it treats `@`s and other special Razor markup stuff as fragments of code to parse.

When you write something like

```
buttonRow.InnerHtml = "@RenderSection('ButtonRow', false)";
```

you merely write raw string to the HTML, string that won't be parsed by Razor.

Comment: Yep I realise thats why its not working - is there a way around it though? For example if you need to generate `@Url.Content`, you can do `var imageUrl = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl("~/Content/images/logo.jpg", helper.ViewContext.HttpContext);`

Comment: It depends, I'm not familiar with your project so I can't answer that one. Almost certainly there is a way, I just can't fiddle with it given the limited environment here.

Answer (score 1):

You render a section outside a layout page like this:

```
public static IHtmlString RenderSectionCustom(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    WebViewPage page = html.ViewDataContainer as WebViewPage;
    var section = page.RenderSection("CustomTop", false);
    return section == null ? MvcHtmlString.Empty : MvcHtmlString.Create(section.ToHtmlString());
}

public static IHtmlString DefineSectionCustom(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    WebViewPage page = html.ViewDataContainer as WebViewPage;

    page.DefineSection("CustomTop", () =>
    {
        page.Write(MvcHtmlString.Create(" hello world (custom top section from HTML HELPER)!"));
    });

    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```